# angular anchors break when switching to html5mode

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an annoying issue I'm not sure there's a solution to;
We run html5mode in production, but not in development. The reason is that this is difficult to setup on spring-boot's embedded tomcat. We are coding our html anchors like this:

```
<a href="/route">Route</a>
```

which of course breaks when not in html5mode where angular will expect the href to be `"#/route"` instead - which is a real pain. The only way we've found to avoid this problem, is to code links like this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="goto('/route')">Route</a>
```

and have a global function in i.e. $rootScope:

```
$scope.goto = function (route) {
    $location.path(route);
}
```

But this just seems wrong. I had hoped that using ng-href insted of href on the anchor would sort this out (perhaps detecting if we are in html5mode or not, and auto-add the hash to the url so that we do not need to refactor the entire app if we switch modes), but it doesn't.

Is there no way of using anchors WITHOUT explicitly stating hash urls?

Comment: <- Have the same problem right now, am also using a method called `goto` -- weird thing is this is only happening on one page in our app. However, our links were only failing if we were using Angular interpolated text in the link text - posted a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684353/angularjs-link-with-variable-as-link-text-doesnt-fire -- might help.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv that's exactly what I want to avoid and what is causing problems for us when we are switching between html5mode and no html5mode. If you read the question at the end I ask how to link using anchors WITHOUT stating hash urls.

Comment: It would seem you gave the answer yourself in the question. You need a directive, not unlike ng-href, that takes html5mode into account. Concatenating a # in front of the URL when not in html5 mode should be straight-forward.

Comment: Hmmm... I was actually hoping I just missed something in the documentation. If Angular is not able to handle routing properly when switching between modes like this, I would actually consider this a design flaw. It should be possible to use html5mode=false in development and make an easy switch to html5mode=true for production without having to replace all hrefs in the application OR create a custom directive to 'hide' the flaw. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I still believe this to be a design flaw in angular, and that this particular fix should exist within angular itself.

This directive is matched directly on the 'href' attribute. I've not done any testing on how this affects performance, but it does perform rewrites on internal url's only.

```
angular.module(_DIRECTIVES_).directive('href', ['$location', function ($location) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict:   'A',
        scope: {
            href: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Check if we need to rewrite the href
            var currentBase = $location.$$protocol + '://' + $location.$$host;
            var newBase     = element[0].href;
            if (element[0].nodeName == 'A' && newBase.indexOf(currentBase) == 0  && !$location.$$html5) {
                // Perform the href AFTER angular has done it's thing. Otherwise angular will rewrite back to the original
                scope.$watch('href', function () {
                    // This function may be run several times. Make sure the rewrite only happens once.
                    if (scope.href.indexOf('#!') !== 0) {
                        scope.href = '#!' + scope.href;
                        element.attr('href', scope.href);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

I hope this will help anybody else in the same predicament as me. Also hope that angular will fix this in the future.